What is this weird 1x2 with hooks on one side and two small bars on the other?
I was looking at my old bricks and found this weird piece. If anyone could help me find the element ID I would be ecstatic. The piece is a weird 1x2 with hooks on one side and two little small bars on the other.

Hi guest and welcome to Bricks.SE! The description alone could refer to many possible interpretations (plate or brick, shorter or longer sides, direction and size of the hooks and bars, etc.), but if you could please upload a photo of this part, that would be a lot clearer. Meanwhile do check if the studs have the LEGO inscription - the absence would mean it is a 3rd party piece, with probably no authentic LEGO equivalent.

It's difficult to identify a part for sure without a picture, but this sounds a lot like Technic Link with Two Studs (273):

It was used as chain links in various sets in the 70s:

